# string value obtained from reading from json file , displays weirdly when using Path.Combine

Tags: c#, .net, json, path

I have a functionality where I would scan a given path for a certain file and process some information based on the information in that file . this file info.json in json syntax has a name and a relative path to a certain  directory .
What I am trying to do is simply obtain the relative path from the json file and print out an absoulute path

the relative file specified in the info.json file is as below,

```
{
  "Name": "testName",
  "OriginalPath": "new/File"
}
```

The absolute path that I am trying to print out is something like :- `D:\testDel\new\File` but the actual value is always something like **`D:\testDel\new/File`** , while I must say this path is still a valid path (when I do a win key + R I can navigate to that directory) but in terms of how its been displayed it looks messy .

Any Idea as to why I might be facing this problem , am I doing something wrong ,

my code is as follows

```
string path = @"D:\testDel";
            IEnumerable<string> foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "info.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (string file in foundFiles)
            {

                DataModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(File.ReadAllText(file));

                string Name = data.Name;
                string absolutePath = data.OriginalPath;
                string folderpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderpath, absolutePath);
                Console.WriteLine(fullPath);

            }
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string OriginalPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `fullPath = Path.Combine(folderpath, absolutePath).Replace("/", "\")`

Comment: thats a very weak solution because 1) its a work around and not really a solution 2) I get an error 
Error CS1010 Newline in constant  @stuartd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Path.Combine(folderpath, absolutePath) statement in a Path.GetFullPath() as

```
fullPath=Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(folderpath, absolutePath));
```

this will also resolve reletive paths like `../NewFil` to `D:\NewFile`

Answer (score 1):

You can update a path, coming from JSON using [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_Char_System_Char_) method and built-in [`Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.8) fields

```cs
string absolutePath = data.OriginalPath.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string folderpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
```

You are right, that path `D:\testDel\new/File` is valid, because Windows supports both, forward slash and backslash